# how to copy from array to array in specific location programmatically in C# winform

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

i have 2 arrays that have this values
i need to copy data from array 2 to array 1 in null places if they have the same ex number
[the 2 arrays and output i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt28r.png)

my code is like this but it only copy one ex to all nulls in array 1
(data as array 1 and x as array 2)

```
 for (int q = 0; q < data.Length; q++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i = i + 4)
                {
                    if (arr1[i] == data[q])
                    {
                        for (int fin = 0; fin < data.Length; fin++)
                        {
                            if (arr1[i] == data[q])
                            {
                                if (data[q + fin] == "end")
                                {
                                    data[q + fin + 1] = arr1[i + 1];
                                    data[q + fin + 2] = arr1[i + 2];
                                    data[q + fin + 3] = arr1[i + 3];
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Given the two arrays you show in the picture, what is the expected output? In addition, have you considered using a `List` as opposed to an array? This may simplify things.

Comment: i modified array 2 to become list cuz i dont know how many items in it 
and Out put should be like this--->
ex1,
green,
green,
end,
17,
last is not complete,
counter on,
ex7 (Sorry it is ex7 not ex1),
red,
green,
end,
11,
Last is done, 
counter on,

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show what the expected output should be. Do not add it in a comment. In addition, you should post the array values as “text” not pictures. No one is going to help if they have to type in the data. From a first glance… it appears the line of code… `if (data[q + fin] == "END")` … will NEVER be true. Strings are Case sensitive “END” != “end”. I suggest you peruse the SO [tour] section as it shows how SO works. The [ask] section may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Comment: i updated the picture please see it and sorry i am new at stack over flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image, it looks like the output array contains every item from array1 in its original location, and items from array2 are slotted into the null spots, but only if those items don't appear in array1. Here is a sample algorithm to do that:

```
public static String[] Merge(String[] arr1, String[] arr2) {
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    int requiredLength = 0;
    foreach (String s in arr1) {
        if (s != null) {
            ht[s] = s;
            requiredLength++;
        }
    }
    foreach (String s in arr2) {
        if (s != null && !ht.ContainsKey(s))
            requiredLength++;
    }

    String[] arr3 = new String[requiredLength];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr3.Length; i++) {
        String s = (i < arr1.Length ? arr1[i] : null);
        if (s == null) {
            while (k < arr2.Length) {
                if (arr2[k] != null && !ht.ContainsKey(arr2[k])) {
                    arr3[i] = arr2[k++];
                    break;
                }
                k++;
            }
        }
        else
            arr3[i] = s;
    }
    return arr3;
}
```

Comment: Really thank you
your answer was very helpful to me